# Is there any way to detect and cut out the real video part from a full video

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

Not sure whether I can explain my question. I have a bunch of video material. Some of them are recorded videos from mobile phones. When people record the video on their phone, their produced video may contain more than just the recorded video I need. I need to detect and cut out the useless part. The useless part would be still while the part I need is changing and on the play.

I do not know whether there is any way for me to do it. I can write some code but I just do not know what libraries to use. Does it have something to do with OpenCV. Or is there a way to solve it with ffmpeg?

Hopefully someone can give me some ideas. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Scene detection might help to some degree. You could try PySceneDetect, there's an example [here](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/usage-example/).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be splitting scenes, not really the one I am looking for